# What is android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT used for in an android application?

Tags: android, process, manifest

I have been trying to figure this out on the web with no information whatsoever as to what this actually does. The Google Manifest information says:

Allows an application to set the maximum number of (not needed) application processes that can be running.

I am thinking this is not a third party app permission but I need to be sure, its for our embedded device.

My guess is that this limits the number of processes that one application can have open when calling android:process=".RemoteActivity" in the manifest.

Anyone? Thank you.

Comment: Um, if it's for your embedded device, you have all the source code for that embedded device -- use `grep` and find out what it is used for.

Comment: So it cannot be used by third party developers then right? - Thank you!

Comment: Well, it is a "dangerous"-level permission, so SDK developers can request and hold it. My point was more that, unless you got lucky, the only thing *we're* going to do is poke around the source code to see where `SET_PROCESS_LIMIT` is referenced, and you can do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a development/debug intended permisson. And just do what it says. Remember that when you run an app, android creates a process for all it's activities. This is, if you start opening the different activities of your application, you use the same process. However, Android let's you choose if an activity uses the main process or another new one. That's why this permission exists.

Sources:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SET_PROCESS_LIMIT